# iOS UIBarButtonItem UIEdgeInsetsMake Not Affecting Size For Right/Left

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm attempting to scale down a button creating with an image using `UIEdgeInsetsMake`. It seems to work on the top/bottom and shrink the image vertically but the right/left seem to have no effect.

Here's how I'm creating the image and attempting to make it smaller. Any idea where I'm going wrong?

```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/ios/images/remove-symbol-white.png"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *homeButton = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];


    //TODO: Check image exists
    self.doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[homeButton imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]
                                                                style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                               target:self
                                                               action: @selector(doneButtonPushed:)];
    self.doneButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(12, 12, 12, 12);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can customsize a view to initial the UIBarButtonItem,like this:
`UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];`

so you can set the UIImageView size you want.

Answer (score 0):

Going off the above answer I resolved it with this:

```
    NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"https://s3.amazonaws.com/ios/images/remove-symbol-white.png"];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    UIImage *homeButton = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[homeButton imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 20);

    self.doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:imageView];
```